# Nuxtjs head title is not changing

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I created a website with NUXT.js and wanted a different head title for every page. So I used the head method like in the documentation (https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/). When I check the head title in the devtools it shows the correct title but in the page source the title still shows the title from my nuxt.config.js.

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
...
head: {
title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
}
...
}
```

test page:

```
export default {
    head () {
        return {
            title: 'Test 1'
        }
    }
}
```

devtools:
[image]

page source:
[image]

I also tried to solve this problem with the titleTemplate property but without success. Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of Nuxt are you working on!

Comment: @HardikShah I am working on nuxt 2.12.2. Apparently this problem is just in spa mode. I changed to universal mode and now the head titles work perfectly. Is this a bug or is this the correct behavior when in spa mode?

Comment: @WithRegenrek SPA is not intended for any search optimization, it's basically your dynamic view layer without server-side rendering, so fetching title in HTML would be premature and unnecessary.